# How to choose cached credential with Microsoft Graph Service Client

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal

I have MSAL identity client app that I am able to use to get access token for a user.

I am now trying to use `Microsoft.Graph.Auth` instead to send requests. Below code shows how MSAL `IndentityClientApp` is passed to `Graph.Auth`.

```
DeviceCodeProvider authProvider = new DeviceCodeProvider(IdentityClientApp, Scopes);
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);
```

I cannot figure how to specify which cached credential to use, if more than one credential is cached.

When I was using MSAL on its own, I was using below code to specify the user account. How do I do this with MS.Graph?

`authResult = await IdentityClientApp.AcquireTokenSilent(Scopes, account).ExecuteAsync();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this approach to create `GraphClient` allows me to control the account that is used:

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(MSGraphURL, new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(async (requestMessage) =>
{
    requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", OutlookToken);
}));
```

[Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-windows-uwp#instantiate-the-microsoft-graph-service-client-by-obtaining-the-token-from-the-signinuserandgettokenusingmsal-method)